# How to mimic a lambda expression returning a value

Tags: c#, .net

Ignoring the irrelevant parts - I have a requirement to use a delegate with no arguments and no return value, but get a value from it.
The current solution is to use a lambda expression and a variable that's declared before it.

```
string result;
RequiredMethod(() => { result = "the result"; });// Gets the result from a 2nd thread.
//use result
```

Is there a way to do this without using a lambda expression? I expect there should be, but can't come up with it.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448010/how-to-declare-a-generic-delegate-with-an-out-parameter

Comment: @PHeiberg He tries to use an `Action` without a lambda that changes the surrounding context. `Func<T>` will not work because it returns the value. The task is to do it without returning it and without lambda.

Comment: Why are you looking for another way? Is there some problem with your current implementation?

Comment: @Luaan This is just an example. The actual code is longer and its readability suffers from its lambdaness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes of course there is:

```
public class ValueHolder
{
    public string Value { get; private set; }

    public void AssignValue()
    {
        this.Value = "the result";
    }
}

// usage
var vh = new ValueHolder();
RequiredMethod(vh.AssignValue);

// access value
vh.Value
```

The code you provided told me that you try to access values from another thread. Please keep in mind that you should not access `vh.Value` until `AssignValue` has been called. You need to add some other code to sync these operations (but your lambda has exactly the same problem).

Comment: Of course, in the end, the lambda does the exact same thing - it just autogenerates that helper class for you.

Comment: @Luaan Yes you're right. But I don't know why a lambda is slower than this solution even if the autogenerated code should look very similar. But that's another topic, we don't discuss that here.

Comment: Perfect and simple. That's exactly what I was trying to do. (And, yes, the threading has to be done carefully anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

also the question is why do you have to use a delegate. If it's about getting the value you could even implement it in a way like this

```
string someString;
RequiredMethod(ref someString);
```

Of course this would change the signature of the RequiredMethod (and the question becomes why you couldn't return a value in the first place.).

You could even write an overload of the 2nd using your lamdba expression.

```
void RequireMethod(string ref variable) { 
     RequireMethod(() => { variable = "the result";});
}
```