# Declare type for a delegate with "out" parameter

Tags: c#, .net

How to declare type for a delegate with "out" parameter?

Example of function with "out" parameter:

```cs
bool TryCalculate(out Data data) => ...;
```

Example of function that should accept `TryCalculate` as paramter:

```cs
void Calculate(Func<Data, bool> tryCalculate)
{
    if (tryCalculate(out var data))
        DoSomething(data);
    
    ...
}
```

The parameter type `Func<Data, bool>` is wrong here (compiler error CS1615). If I define type like `Func<out Data, bool>`, then `out` become variance modifier.

Example of use:

```cs
Calculate(TryCalculate);
```

Comment: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/q/1283127/12888024 2) https://stackoverflow.com/q/2448010/12888024

Comment: @aepot, yes it answering my question, thank you.